# Passing variable value in CSVRead function in Jmeter

Tags: function, variables, groovy, parameters, jmeter

We are trying to use csvread function in Jmeter to enable sequential each occurrence picking of values from csv file.
Groovy code tries to create a string - CustomLineItem by concatenating all values from the csv file -- abc.csv sequentially and use the concatenated string later on.

However despite all attempts to pass on a variable column count to csvread, function is still picking up column number 2 every time as the default value of user defined variable itemcount is 1

Any clues or hints would are highly appreciated.

```
for( i= 1 ; i<=${LineItemcount}; i++) 
       {  
vars.put("itemcount",i.toString());
CustomLineItem =  "{ \"orderItemId\": \"\", \"cin\": \"" +${__CSVRead(abc.csv,${itemcount})}+ "\",\"longLineSTP\": \"\", \"quantity\": \"1\", \"lineItemDeleted\": false, \"lineItemModified\": true, \"staleProductInfo\": true}, \r\n" 
LineitemString = LineitemString + CustomLineItem ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which says:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code **does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So you either need to move your `${LineItemcount}` to Parameters section like:

[image]

or replace it with [**vars** shorthand to JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) call:

```
for( i= 1 ; i<=vars.get('LineItemcount') as int; i++)
```

The same applies to using __CSVRead() function